# Can Labview simulate the electrical circuits like Pspice?

Tags: labview

I really need to know that can I simulate the simple circuits like RC, OP-AMP, RL, or RLC in labview?

Or it can only make processes for recorded signals?
I think, it cannot create and simulate the electrical circuits like pscpice or simulink.

Please help me if you know it cannot 100% work.

Answer (score 1):

LabVIEW is a tool for graphical programming.

Of course, you can (try to) build up a simulation tool with it, similiar to what you would do in C, but you'd have to do it completely by hand, as the authors of the several *Spice did as well.

It definitely cannot simulate anything Spice-like. It is as if you would ask if you could do compiling from within Excel, or do database management with Paint.

Answer (score 0):

LabVIEW cannot simulate circuits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for general-purpose software that can capture and simulate electronic circuits, LabVIEW is not suitable.

If you want to simulate specific, simple circuits like the ones you list, for which you can easily define the set of equations that determine their behaviour, you should be able to do it in LabVIEW, using the [mathematics functions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/gmath/mathematics/) for example. This would make most sense if you wanted to link your simulation with some other function of LabVIEW such as hardware input/output, graphing, data analysis etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your circuit simulator is in another castle!

I would recommend another tool (from National Instruments) called Multisim.

http://www.ni.com/multisim/